# AWS SQS asynchronous query listener with java and spring. How to plug values from environment variables into @MessageMapping annotation

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have an bunch of queues in Amazon SQS and i have an asynchronous queue listener running in a spring service. I followed [this tutorial](https://codemason.me/2016/03/12/amazon-aws-sqs-with-spring-cloud/) and it works like a charm. My problem is, I can't just hard-code the queue name into the @MessageMapping annotation, I need to be able to grab it from user defined environment variables. Here's the bit I'm talking about...

```
@MessageMapping("queueName")
public void onSQSMessage(String payload) {
    //handle payload
}
```

If i just hard code the queue name this works great, but it needs to be from the environment variables. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use expression language since a while.

```
@MessageMapping(${"queueName"})
public void onSQSMessage(String payload) {
    //handle payload
}
```

See the JIRA issue:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13271

Comment: Ah I did try that but I got a "could not resolve placeholder" exception. It seems to only work when that named value is in the application.properties file.

Comment: What was the name of your environment variable and what placeholder name did you use? Because there maybe a transformation of the variable. Like PERSON_FIRST_NAME to person.first.name

Comment: The variable was un-nested in the JSON string of my VCAP_SERVICES env and it was called "backup_data_queue_name" and that's how i referenced it

Comment: Probably MessageMapping is not working with CloudFoundry environment variables. Can you provide the queue name as "normal" environment variable?

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot. This needs to come from the VCAP_SERVICES as I need to be able to roll out this application to multiple tenants with different queue names

Comment: Then maybe there is no solution for you problem